# iPhone - How to draw text in the middle of a rect

Tags: iphone

Is there a method to draw text in the middle of a rectangle.  I can find various alignments, but nothing I have tried can vertically centre the text in a rect.

Is there a simple method to do this, or is there some way to centre a rectangle and then draw in that?

I'm drawing direct to the CGContext, trying to use NSString::drawWithRect or something similar, as I dont really want to have to add a Label just to render some basic text.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, the font property `pointSize` corresponds directly to the height in pixels of a `NSString` drawn in that `UIFont`, so your formula would be something like this:

```
- (void) drawString: (NSString*) s 
           withFont: (UIFont*) font 
             inRect: (CGRect) contextRect {

    CGFloat fontHeight = font.pointSize;
    CGFloat yOffset = (contextRect.size.height - fontHeight) / 2.0;

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(0, yOffset, contextRect.size.width, fontHeight);

    [s drawInRect: textRect 
         withFont: font 
    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeClip 
        alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

`UITextAlignmentCenter` handles the `horizontal` centering, so we use the full width of the contextRect.  The `lineBreakMode` can be whatever you like.

Comment: This is very close to what I eventually went with.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, I know this is quite old but I just used it and had to make a change.

My change was the CGRect textRect... line.  I changed it to...

CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(contextRect.origin.x, contextRect.origin.y + yOffSet, contextRect.size.width, fontHeight);

Comment: Hi, I also know this is quite old, but I also had to make a small change. I needed to change the way to calculate the fontHeight to get a proper center: CGFloat fontHeight = [s sizeWithFont:font].height; Any clue why this is different compared to the better looking font.pointSize?

Comment: I agree with this answer, except for a small change: I use font.lineSize to get the proper height. I assume that sizeWithFont will give you the lineSize as well.

Answer (score 18):

Here's an updated version for iOS7.0+.

I've also improved on the above answer by using the `sizeWithAttributes:` method which returns the bounds of the text enabling you to properly position the text before drawing it. This removes the need to hardcode any adjustments which will break if you use a different size font or if you use a different font.

```
- (void) drawString: (NSString*) s
           withFont: (UIFont*) font
             inRect: (CGRect) contextRect {

    /// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    /// Set line break mode
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    /// Set text alignment
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: font,
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle };

    CGSize size = [s sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(contextRect.origin.x + floorf((contextRect.size.width - size.width) / 2),
                                 contextRect.origin.y + floorf((contextRect.size.height - size.height) / 2),
                                 size.width,
                                 size.height);

    [s drawInRect:textRect withAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
static func draw(_ text: String, _ rect: CGRect, _ font: UIFont) {

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    let attributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red
    ]
    NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes).draw(in: rect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: (rect.height - font.pointSize)/2))
}
```

If you want to draw multiple lines,

```
 func drawMutipleLine(text: String = "Good morning how \nare you ,  fine, thank\nyou good day. uck wood?", 
                    _ rect: CGRect, 
                      font: UIFont =  UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 15)!) -> UIImage {

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: rect.size)
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 15)!
        let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font:font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        let numLines = text.split(separator: "\n").count + 1
        NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes).draw(in: rect.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: (rect.height - font.pointSize * CGFloat(numLines))/2))
    }
    return image
}
```

Comment: how can i draw with multiline

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6 you get attributed strings and paragraph alignments, so this becomes a lot more straightforward and powerful. In this example we draw a big red "A" in the middle of a rectangle:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* p = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
p.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSAttributedString* bigA = 
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"A" attributes:@{
         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:100],
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],
         NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: p
    }];
[bigA drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
```

Comment: That centers the text horizontally, but doesn't vertically align it.

Comment: "Vertically align"? Just draw it where you want it. Or draw it in something (e.g. an image) and put that where you want it.

Comment: Right -- I understand what you're saying. I was just trying to point out that I think the question was about how to align something vertically at the center of something larger. Given a predetermined `NSRect`, for example, how can you use `[myString drawInRect:myRect]` or a variant to position the string at the vertical center of `myRect`. For Cocoa, I do it by including the `NS(Attributed)String+Geometrics` category from https://github.com/jerrykrinock/CategoriesObjC and doing a bit of simple math with the `- (float)heightForWidth:(float)width` method.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with amagrammer's answer, except for a small change: I use `font.lineSize` to get the proper height. I assume that `sizeWithFont` will give you the lineSize as well

Comment: I agree with you, but lineSize or lineHeight ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this code works pretty well:

```
NSString *text = @"A bit of text to draw";
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGRect textFrame = (CGRect)
{
    .size.width = 150,
    .size.height = 150,
};
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:textFrame.size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect newTextFrame = CGRectInset(textFrame, 0, (textFrame.size.height - textSize.height) / 2);
[text drawInRect:newTextFrame withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

The text, font and containing frame can come from anywhere, so just use the same line break mode when you do the calculation and the drawing.