# How to draw a long string on UIImage In SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, draw, drawtext

I am trying to draw long string on UIImage but unable to achieve . Currently when i draw the text on image only one line shows .

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bottomImage = UIImage(named: "2")
    let text = "SwiftUI helps you build great-looking apps across all Apple platforms with the power of Swift — and surprisingly little code."
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                Image(uiImage: bottomImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                Button {
                    drawTextOnImage()
                } label: {
                    Text("DrawText")
                }
            }
    }
    func drawTextOnImage(){
        let newSize = CGSize(width: 660, height: 700)
        let topNew = UIImage(named: "3")

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        topNew!.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        let text_style=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        text_style.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
//        text_style.numberOfLines = 0
        text_style.alignment=NSTextAlignment.center
        let text_color=UIColor.yellow
        let attributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.font:font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:text_style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:text_color]
        let text_h=font.lineHeight
        let text_y=((topNew?.size.height)!-text_h)/1.2
        let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: text_y, width: (topNew?.size.width)!, height: text_h)
        text.draw(in: text_rect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bottomImage = newImage
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Achieved Result** :

[image: Only One line text is drawn on the image]
**Expected Result** : i want to show the whole string saved in **text** variable on the top of UIImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on here, but the main issue you're facing is in `let text_h=font.lineHeight`. By limiting the height of the drawable rectangle to the line height, there's not enough vertical space to wrap the text. Additionally, since you've already defined a size for the new image in `let newSize = CGSize(width: 660, height: 700)`, referencing the asset's size will give you bounds that are different than your drawable area. You might also want to use `.byWordWrapping` instead of `.byTruncatingTail` for your line break mode if you want to see every word on the image instead of "...".

**Here's a modification of your `drawTextOnImage()` function addressing those points:**

```
func drawTextOnImage() {
    let newSize = CGSize(width: 660, height: 700)
    let topNew = UIImage(named: "3")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    topNew!.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
    
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    let text_style=NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    text_style.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    text_style.alignment=NSTextAlignment.center
    let text_color=UIColor.yellow
    let attributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.font:font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle:text_style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:text_color]
    
    // Center the text on the finished image
    let text_y=((newSize.height - font.pointSize)/2)
    let text_rect=CGRect(x: 0, y: text_y, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
    text.draw(in: text_rect, withAttributes: attributes)
    
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.bottomImage = newImage
    }
}
```

What's changed? We're calculating the center based on the font's size (thanks to [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53041868/20422552)), referencing your variable defined image dimensions, and are instructing the text to wrap instead of truncate.

**Result:**

[image: Simulator Screenshot of code result]

As a bonus, if `UIImage(named: "2")` and `UIImage(named: "3")` are the same image, you can just call `UIImage(named: "2")` both times. Drawing doesn't mutate the image in the asset catalog in any way.